# Clarification on customSchema usage while reading with JDBC using pyspark

Tags: jdbc, pyspark

I am using Oracle JDBC connector to read tables using pyspark. There are some columns for which I want to define my own customSchema while reading. So for example if I have a table EMP where a column "EMP_ID" is having Number as datatype in Oracle, I want it to be IntegerType in Spark

Below is the code which I am using:

c_schema = 'EMP_ID INT'

config = {'user':'xxx','password':'xxx','driver':'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','customSchema':c_schema}

df = spark.read.jdbc(url='jdbc:oracle:thin@dbServerhost/ServiceName',table='EMP',properties=config)

However, the issue is when I am doing : df.printSchema(), its is showing the type as 'decimal(38,10)' not as a Integer or decimal(x,0)

I also tried c_schema = 'EMP_ID DECIMAL(20,0)' but there is no change in the spark datatype. Its still showing Decimal(38,10)

Could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong and why the column datatype is not changing when I am doing pyspark jdbc read?

I am using Spark 2.3.2 with Python 3.6

Comment: Have you tried in lowercase like c_schema = emp_id DECIMAL(38,0) may sound idiotic but what if it is case sensitive. As stated in documentation "The column names should be identical to the corresponding column names of JDBC table"

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well but no luck

Comment: Any suggestions guys?

Comment: @SanjeevRoy did you ever figure this one out?